# How to Update a generic list passed by reference to a method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic list of messages, which I pass to a method by reference. 
The method uses one of the messages from the list and updates the message.

How do I get this message updated with a new text, when passing the entire list by reference?

e.g.

```
private int RetrieveAndProcessQueueEntityRows(
        string sEntityCode,
        string sMessageFIDs,
        int iNumberToFetch,
        ref List<Entity> oMessageList) {

////......

Message currMessage = null;

foreach (Message oMessage in oMessageList) {
     if (oMessage.Message_UID == oPatientInfoEntityCurrent.MessageFID) {
        currMessage = oMessage;
        break;
     }
}
```

So now I can use the currMessage object to do the required updates. But how do I update the `List<Entity> oMessageList` with the `currMessage`?

Thanks for all your help!
 - Lakus

Comment: Should that be a List<Message>? or is that a base-class...

Comment: Oh, and on a purely stylistic note - unless your team's guidelines demand it, you might want to get out of the Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 6):

If the message is a class, you don't need to pass *any* of it by reference; you simply either update the existing message object, or create a new message object and swap it in the list (via the indexer, or with Remove/Add).

You only need `ref` if you are creating a new list.

So if `Message` is a mutable class, just:

```
currMessage.SomeProperty = "some value"; // done
```

If not, use the `oMessageList`'s indexer (or, as stated `Add`/`Remove`) - i.e.

```
oMessageList[index] = replacementMessage;
```

Note that if you do change the list contents during the `foreach`, the `foreach` iterator will almost certainly break; there are ways of handling that, but if you can: just update a property of the message itself.